# How to Index SQL with multiple AND conditions nested inside OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, query-planner

I want to speed up the following sql (cost is 19685.75). Can I index this sql which have multiple complex nested AND conditions combining with OR in the WHERE statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON ("crawler_url"."url") U0."id"
FROM "characteristics_text" U0 LEFT OUTER
JOIN "characteristics_text_urls"
    ON (U0."id" = "characteristics_text_urls"."text_id") LEFT OUTER
JOIN "crawler_url"
    ON ("characteristics_text_urls"."url_id" = "crawler_url"."id")
WHERE ( 
    (
        U0."publication_date" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
        AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U0."publication_date") = 10
    )
        OR 
    (
        U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
        AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U0."lastmod") = 10
    )
        OR 
    (
        U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" IS NULL
        AND U0."created_at" BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00+08:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999+08:00'
        AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U0."created_at" AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Hong_Kong') = 10
    )
        OR 
    (
        U0."publication_date" >= '2018-08-01'
        AND U0."publication_date" < '2018-10-31'
    )
        OR 
    (
        U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" >='2018-08-01'
        AND U0."lastmod" < '2018-10-31'
    )
        OR 
    (
        U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" IS NULL
        AND U0."created_at" >= '2018-07-31 16:00:00+00:00'
        AND U0."created_at" < '2018-10-30 16:00:00+00:00'
    ) 
)
ORDER BY  "crawler_url"."url" ASC, U0."created_at" DESC
```

The table text contains the following fields and indexs (some other fields are not shown)

```
                                            Table "public.characteristics_text"                                                                                                     
            Column         |           Type           |                             Modifiers                                                                                        
    ------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------                                                           
    id                     | integer                  | not null default nextval('characteristics_text_id_seq'::regclass)
    text                   | text                     | 
    created_at             | timestamp with time zone | not null
    lastmod                | date                     | 
    publication_date       | date                     | 
    Indexes:
        "characteristics_text_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "characteristics_text_fde81f11" btree (created_at)
        "characteristics_text_lastmod_3bff34c2_uniq" btree (lastmod)
        "characteristics_text_publication_date_772c1bda_uniq" btree (publication_date)
        "characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx" btree (publication_date, lastmod, created_at)
```

I added three single indexes for created_at, lastmod and publication_date; and one multiple-column index for these fields.

But in postgres EXPAIN query, this where clause is still using **Seq Scan** but not **Index Scan**.

```
->  Seq Scan on characteristics_text u0  (cost=0.00..19685.75 rows=14535 width=12)
    Filter: (
            (
                (publication_date >= '2018-01-01'::date) AND 
                (publication_date <= '2018-12-31'::date) AND 
                (
                        date_part(
                            'month'::text, (publication_date)::timestamp without time zone
                ) = 10::double precision)
            ) OR 

                ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-01-01'::date) AND (lastmod <= '2018-12-31'::date) AND (date_part('month'::text, (lastmod)::timestamp without time zone) = 10::double precision)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2017-12-31 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2018-12-31 15:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date_part('month'::text, timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong'::text, created_at)) = 10::double precision)) OR ((publication_date >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (publication_date < '2018-10-31'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (lastmod < '2018-10-31'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2018-07-31 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2018-10-30 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
)
```

My questions are:
1. Is it possible to make postgres to use Index scan for this complex SELECT clause?
2. Do I need to create one multiple-column index for each AND clauses? For example creating a index `(publication_date, lastmod)` in this causes?

```
    (
        U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
        AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U0."lastmod") = 10
    )
```

3. Does index works on searching IS NULL? Do field searching for IS NULL need to be index?

**UPDATED 4nov2018**

When I try minimize the query by testing the fields one by one, fields `publication_date` and `last_mod` trigger index scan individually, while `created_at` can't:

Is it because `created_at` is timestamp? But how come index not work for timestamp?

```
explain SELECT DISTINCT
    ON ("crawler_url"."url") U0."id"
FROM "characteristics_text" U0 LEFT OUTER
JOIN "characteristics_text_urls"
    ON (U0."id" = "characteristics_text_urls"."text_id") LEFT OUTER
JOIN "crawler_url"
    ON ("characteristics_text_urls"."url_id" = "crawler_url"."id")
WHERE ( 
(
        U0."created_at" BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00+08:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999+08:00'
        AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U0."created_at" AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Hong_Kong') = 10
    )   
)
ORDER BY  "crawler_url"."url" ASC, U0."created_at" DESC



Unique  (cost=18004.05..18006.01 rows=393 width=86)
->  Sort  (cost=18004.05..18005.03 rows=393 width=86)
        Sort Key: crawler_url.url, u0.created_at
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..17987.11 rows=393 width=86)
            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..17842.25 rows=393 width=16)
                    ->  Seq Scan on characteristics_text u0  (cost=0.00..15467.37 rows=393 width=12)
                        Filter: ((created_at >= '2017-12-31 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2018-12-31 15:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date_part('month'::text, timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong'::text, created_at)) = 10::double precision))
                    ->  Index Scan using characteristics_text_urls_65eb77fe on characteristics_text_urls  (cost=0.42..6.03 rows=1 width=8)
                        Index Cond: (u0.id = text_id)
            ->  Index Scan using crawler_url_pkey on crawler_url  (cost=0.29..0.36 rows=1 width=78)
                    Index Cond: (characteristics_text_urls.url_id = id)
```

`publication_date` seems trigger index scan:

```
(
    U0."publication_date" IS NULL
    AND U0."lastmod" >='2018-08-01'
    AND U0."lastmod" < '2018-10-31'
)


Unique  (cost=17053.26..17085.63 rows=6473 width=86)
->  Sort  (cost=17053.26..17069.44 rows=6473 width=86)
        Sort Key: crawler_url.url, u0.created_at
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11130.73..16643.51 rows=6473 width=86)
            ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=11130.44..14257.63 rows=6473 width=16)
                    Hash Cond: (characteristics_text_urls.text_id = u0.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on characteristics_text_urls  (cost=0.00..1858.01 rows=120601 width=8)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=11049.53..11049.53 rows=6473 width=12)
                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on characteristics_text u0  (cost=186.95..11049.53 rows=6473 width=12)
                                Recheck Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (lastmod < '2018-10-31'::date))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx  (cost=0.00..185.33 rows=6473 width=0)
                                    Index Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (lastmod < '2018-10-31'::date))
            ->  Index Scan using crawler_url_pkey on crawler_url  (cost=0.29..0.36 rows=1 width=78)
                    Index Cond: (characteristics_text_urls.url_id = id)
```

Comment: Start by reducing your query to just a SELECT on that table with one of your WHERE conditions. See if it uses the index. If so, keep adding until you find out which one of those causes a seq scan, and go from there.

Comment: @eurotrash seems the planner auto switch to seq scan for `created_at`, see above UPDATED 4nov2018 section

Comment: Two thoughts. Firstly get rid of the call to `EXTRACT`, that is already something which won't work with your index. You should only have `U0."created_at" BETWEEN...` remaining. Secondly, you're looking for `created_at` throughout a whole year. Is it a large percentage of records in the table? If so, that could be why it's not using the index.  If not, I strongly suspect it's to do with the timezones. I never use timezones myself so can't advise here, but I'm aware queries involving timezones may not always use indexes as expected.

Comment: @eurotrash your are right, the whole year of 2018 has 60% out of 100,000 records. I actually just want October data. I wrote this strange `EXTRACT` statement because it is generate from django function finding month https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month. Should have use `BETWEEN '2018-10-01 00:00:00+08:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999+08:00'`

Answer (score 2):

OK, a Full Table Scan (seq_scan) can actually be faster than multiple Index Scans. It depends on the specific "selectivity" of your filtering conditions.

First of all your `WHERE` clause has six filtering conditions that are `OR`ed. That means that if you wanted to use indexes, PostgreSQL would need to use it 6 times, and then perform a "Index OR" to merge the results. That may not be cheap.

So first, you need to know what's the expected selectivity of each one of the 6 filtering conditions. This is, how many rows are selected, compared to the total number of rows the table has. Do it; a few simple SQL queries will give you the answer. Post the answer here.

Now, if the sum of all six selectivities is more than 5%, then a Full Table Scan (the algorithm you have now) is faster. Don't bother with indexes.

Otherwise, the following index can help:

```
create index ix1 on characteristics_text (
  publication_date, 
  lastmod,
  created_at,
  1);
```

Comment: yes, the whole year of 2018 has 60% out of 100,000 records. Changing from `BEWEEN` the whole year to `BETWEEN '2018-10-01 00:00:00+08:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999+08:00'` give index scan.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you are going to get an index that is useful here.   What you might consider doing is breaking this query into 4 or 5 parts, and then using UNION to stick the results together again.  (UNION will remove dupes, WHILE UNION ALL will return all rows).

UNION is a fairly expensive operation, so there is some consideration in how many rows this returns.  Using the index may buy more efficiency than the UNION loses if it removes a sufficient number of rows.   If many rows are returned, your current form is about as good as it is going to get.

Answer (score 0):

The whole year of 2018 has 60% out of 100,000 records, which made the database use seq scan. Changing from BEWEEN the whole year to just one month gives index scan.

```
  AND U0."created_at" >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00'
    AND U0."created_at" <= '2018-10-31 23:59:59.999999+00:00')
```

Full SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON ("crawler_url"."url") U0."id"
FROM "characteristics_text" U0 LEFT OUTER
JOIN "characteristics_text_urls"
    ON (U0."id" = "characteristics_text_urls"."text_id") LEFT OUTER
JOIN "crawler_url"
    ON ("characteristics_text_urls"."url_id" = "crawler_url"."id")
WHERE (
        (U0."publication_date" >= '2018-10-01'
        AND U0."publication_date" <= '2018-11-01')

        OR (U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" >= '2018-10-01'
        AND U0."lastmod" <= '2018-11-01'
        )

        OR 

        (U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" IS NULL
        AND U0."created_at" >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00'
        AND U0."created_at" <= '2018-10-31 23:59:59.999999+00:00')

        OR 

        (U0."publication_date" >= '2018-08-01'
        AND U0."publication_date" < '2018-10-31')

        OR 

        (U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" >= '2018-08-01'
        AND U0."lastmod" < '2018-10-31')

        OR 

        (U0."publication_date" IS NULL
        AND U0."lastmod" IS NULL
        AND U0."created_at" >= '2018-07-31 16:00:00+00:00'
        AND U0."created_at" < '2018-10-30 16:00:00+00:00')
    )
ORDER BY  "crawler_url"."url" ASC
```

EXPLAIN statement shows index scan for each AND conditions, so total have 6 index scans.

```
Unique  (cost=22885.16..22962.39 rows=15446 width=88)
->  Sort  (cost=22885.16..22923.77 rows=15446 width=88)
        Sort Key: crawler_url.url
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=18669.29..21068.51 rows=15446 width=88)
            Hash Cond: (crawler_url.id = characteristics_text_urls.url_id)
            ->  Seq Scan on crawler_url  (cost=0.00..1691.88 rows=55288 width=88)
            ->  Hash  (cost=18476.21..18476.21 rows=15446 width=8)
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=14982.09..18476.21 rows=15446 width=8)
                        Hash Cond: (characteristics_text_urls.text_id = u0.id)
                        ->  Seq Scan on characteristics_text_urls  (cost=0.00..1907.25 rows=115525 width=8)
                        ->  Hash  (cost=14789.01..14789.01 rows=15446 width=4)
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on characteristics_text u0  (cost=516.57..14789.01 rows=15446 width=4)
                                    Recheck Cond: (((publication_date >= '2018-10-01'::date) AND (publication_date <= '2018-11-01'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-10-01'::date) AND (lastmod <= '2018-11-01'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2018-10-31 23:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone)) OR ((publication_date >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (publication_date < '2018-10-31'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (lastmod < '2018-10-31'::date)) OR ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2018-07-31 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2018-10-30 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)))
                                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=516.57..516.57 rows=16081 width=0)
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_772c1bda_uniq  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=11 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date >= '2018-10-01'::date) AND (publication_date <= '2018-11-01'::date))
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx  (cost=0.00..6.49 rows=166 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-10-01'::date) AND (lastmod <= '2018-11-01'::date))
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx  (cost=0.00..14.61 rows=413 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2018-10-31 23:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_772c1bda_uniq  (cost=0.00..74.61 rows=3419 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (publication_date < '2018-10-31'::date))
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx  (cost=0.00..108.20 rows=3503 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod >= '2018-08-01'::date) AND (lastmod < '2018-10-31'::date))
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on characteristics_text_publication_date_c6311385_idx  (cost=0.00..284.95 rows=8569 width=0)
                                                Index Cond: ((publication_date IS NULL) AND (lastmod IS NULL) AND (created_at >= '2018-07-31 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at < '2018-10-30 16:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
```